# Set a public attribute as private

Tags: c++, methods, attributes, private, dijkstra

In

```
class vertex{

    // ...

};
```

I'm tryng to set this public attribute as private.

```
vector<edge> edges;
```

But here

```
void addedge(int from, int to, int length=-1) {
    vertices[from].edges.push_back(edge(to, length));
}
```

And here

```
edge &e = vertices[u].edges[i];
```

I can't understand how I can have access to edge with a method like in other cases.

Complete code:

```
#define MAX_VER 1000
#define INFINITE 9999
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class edge{
    private:
        int to;
        int length;
    public:
        edge(int to, int length) : to(to), length(length) {}
        int getTo(){return to;};
        void setTo(int t){to=t;};
        int getL(){return length;};
        void setL(int l){length=l;};
};
class vertex{
    private:
        //vector<edge> edges;
        int dis;
        int prev;
    public:
        vector<edge> edges;

        vector<edge> get_edges(){return edges;}

        int getDis(){return dis;};
        void setDis(int d){dis=d;};
        int getPrev(){return prev;};
        void setPrev(int p){prev=p;};
};
class graph{
    private:
        vertex vertices[MAX_VER];
    public:
        void reset() {
            for (int i=0; i < MAX_VER; i++) {
                vertices[i].get_edges().clear();
                vertices[i].setDis(INFINITE);
                vertices[i].setPrev(-1);
            }
        }

        void addedge(int from, int to, int length=-1) {
            vertices[from].edges.push_back(edge(to, length));
        }
        typedef pair<int, int> pp;
        void dijkstra(int source) {
            priority_queue<pp, vector<pp>, greater<pp> > q;
            vertices[source].setDis(0);
            q.push(make_pair(0, source));
            while (!q.empty()) {
                int u = q.top().second;
                int dis = q.top().first;
                q.pop();
                if (dis > vertices[u].getDis())
                    continue;
                for (int i = 0; i < vertices[u].get_edges().size(); i++) {
                    edge &e = vertices[u].edges[i];
                    if (dis + e.getL() < vertices[e.getTo()].getDis()) {
                        vertices[e.getTo()].setDis(dis + e.getL());
                        vertices[e.getTo()].setPrev(u);
                        q.push(make_pair(vertices[e.getTo()].getDis(), e.getTo()));
                    }
                }
            }
            cout << "Distance from vertex 2 to 4 is: " << vertices[4].getDis() << endl;
        }
};
int main() {
    graph g;
    g.reset();
    g.addedge(0, 1, 5);
    g.addedge(0, 2, 9);
    g.addedge(0, 3, 4);
    g.addedge(0, 4, 6);
    g.addedge(1, 2, 2);
    g.addedge(1, 3, 5);
    g.addedge(1, 4, 7);
    g.addedge(2, 3, 1);
    g.addedge(2, 4, 8);
    g.addedge(3, 4, 3);
    g.dijkstra(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your get_edges method returns edges by value, you want to return them by reference. However the result will be practically the same as when you leave the edges public. I guess what you really want to do is to write methods like addEdge and getEdge to your vertex class to work with edges instead of exposing them publicly.

Comment: Use your `get_edges` function if you want access to the `edges` variable from outside the class.

Comment: `vector<edge> getEgdes() const` should do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`edges` **should** be a private member, accessible via public `get` function. You have defined something like this (`get_edges()`), but it's not defined properly:

```
class vertex
{
    //...

public:
    vector<edge> edges;

    vector<edge> get_edges(){return edges;}

    //...
};
```

You return member via value, which means, that every time this function is called, a **new copy** of `edges` is created and that copy is returned!

You should return it by reference and provide version for both `const` and `non-const` object:

```
class vertex
{
    //...

public:
    vector<edge> edges;

    vector<edge>& get_edges() { return edges; }
    const vector<edge>& get_edges() const { return edges; }

    //...
};
```

Also, `edges` is used only by class `graph`. So probably it would be enough to declare friendship between these two classes?

Change `vertex` class this way:

```
class vertex
{
    friend class graph; //declare friend

private:
    int dis;
    int prev;
    vector<edge> edges; //make 'edges' private

public:
   vector<edge>& get_edges() { return edges; }
   const vector<edge>& get_edges() const { return edges; }
};
```

From now on, `graph` class will have access to all private and protected members of `vertex` class, because it has been declared as its friend. In simple cases, this is the fastest and less-intrusive solution (but only in terms of additional code, that needs to be written).

Comment: Many thanks for the help. Just one other thing. Let me know if declaring a class friend of another, I respect the constraints of encapsulation and OOP?

Comment: Yes, definitely. OOP is also about defining complete, minimal and functional public interface for every class. But sometimes, another class may require access to few or more private members. Adding a lot of new function just to satisfy other class' implementation logic would be a very bad design.